# Invalid website error message while spinning up a kentico11 site

Tags: kentico, kentico-11

I am going through the kentico11 developer essential training and the first requirement is to setup a kentico11 site. I followed the instructions and when done this is all I get

Error Message:

Either the website is stopped or the requested domain name is not configured for any website: http://localhost/Kentico11/CMSMessages/invalidwebsite.aspx
If you're an administrator of this site, you need to go to Sites and make sure the following domain name is configured either in the site properties or a domain alias of a running web site: localhost

How do I proceed? I applied the license in the training package

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added the license for the domain you are using to run the site, you need to add the domain to the *Site domain name* field in the Sites application in Kentico.

1. Open the *Sites* application.
2. Edit (pencil icon) the site.
3. Type the domain into the *Site domain name* property on the General tab - since you are running the site under localhost, simply add `localhost` to the field.
4. Click Save.

Now when you visit the homepage, the error message should no longer appear.

Documentation reference:
https://docs.xperience.io/k11/configuring-kentico/managing-sites/setting-domain-names-for-sites

Comment: The problem that happened was that when I went to the sites application, everything was empty. I only saw the buttons for the "New site wizard" and other buttons so there was no option to select a pencil. Also the dancing goat and other default applications did not get installed.